# Inheritance in test classes

Tags: design, unit-testing, tdd, inheritance, composition

I have an interface `Serializer` with methods `serialize` and `isSerializerFor`. I created a first implementation of this using TDD, and ended up with a nice clean test case fully covering a nice clean implementation. To get a more concrete idea, here is [one relevant commit](https://github.com/wmde/WikibaseDataModelSerialization/pull/1/files).

Now someone else (who is not used to doing TDD) started with writing the second implementation of this `Serializer` interface. This person figured the test needed for the second implementation would have some overlap with my initial test. So an [abstract base class for serializer tests](https://github.com/wmde/WikibaseDataModelSerialization/pull/2/files) was created, holding the methods that are suspected to be common to all serializer test cases.

I'm not happy with this for two main reasons. First of all, the only reason inheritance is used here is for code reuse, which is a big code smell. Secondly, this breaks the TDD cycle. If I now want to create another implementation of `Serializer`, and create a derivative of the base test class, I end up having to implement all production code in one step.

On the other hand, simply duplicating the common code in the test classes seems rather odd as well. I'm hoping composition can be used here in a sane way to avoid these problems.

This seems like a reasonably common situation. How would you solve this? What would you do differently?

Comment: You could create a test class that tests against the interface (i.e. `isSerializerFor`) and use something like [parameterized tests](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=parameterizedTests&r=2.5). Anything implementation specific could then be in a different test specific to just that implementation.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to the people problem (ie. go talk to whoever created the abstract base class) or are you looking for technical solutions that would resolve something else?  Please [edit] your question to make it more clear what you need answered.

Comment: @GlenH7 I'm looking for a solution the the issues I outlined. Not sure which part you think is unclear - can you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 6):

> First of all, the only reason inheritance is used here is for code reuse, which is a big code smell.

Different serializer implementations (like `SerializerA`, `SerializerB`, `SerializerC`) lead to different `SerializerTest` classes (`SerializerTestA`, `SerializerTestB`, `SerializerTestC`), which are all "Serializer testers", giving your a "is-a" relationship to the common `SerializerTester` base class, so inheritance is probably the right tool here.

> If I now want to create another implementation of Serializer, and create a derivative of the base test class, I end up having to implement all production code in one step.

I don't think so. You start TDD by creating a test class `SerializerTestA` (derived from `SerializerTester`, with nothing more than creating a `SerializerA` object. This won't compile - test is RED. Then you implement `SerializerA` with nothing more than a constructor and empty method implementations for the `Serializer` interface  - test is GREEN. Next, you add your first test method to `SerializerTestA`, which may just delegate a test call to a corresponding method in `SerializerTester`. Because of the missing implementations in `SerializerA`, your test fails - RED again. Then, you implement the first empty method in `SerializerA`, until your first does not fail any more - test status is GREEN again.

So, as long as you don't call any test methods from `SerializerTester` needing the full implementation of the `Serializer` class you can still do this step-by-step, staying on the classic TDD path.

Comment: In the environment I am using, which is PHP+PHPUnit, calling tests in SerializerTester is not needed for them to run. PHPUnit will run all test cases in your test class, which includes all inherited ones. I could change the methods in the base class so they are regular methods and not test methods, and then explicitly invoke them one by one. Though then one ends up with those invocations in every test, which is not far from the original situation in terms of duplication.

Comment: @JeroenDeDauw: The original situation was that you had to duplicate the *test implementations*, now you only have to duplicate the *test invocations*, I would consider that as a big difference. Nevertheless, for TDD you need a way to switch your tests "on" incrementally and individually for every serializer class. If that really bothers you still and you want to remove that duplicate invocation code after you have all your tests in place ...

Comment: ... then you could add an additional `SerializerTesterAll` class, derived from `SerializerTester`, with one test method for each regular method in `SerializerTester`, calling that method, and once you have your `SerializerTestA` complete, refactor it by changing its base class from `SerializerTest` to `SerializerTesterAll` and remove all the duplicate test invocations.